# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy exception. in getId of an entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working with hibernate and I want to check if an object is persist or not so i use the `getId` method to check it's value. but as the object is not from this session I get the exception 
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy` . how else can I understand this? note that `id` is the primary key of my object and as far as I know it shouldn't be lazy!!

Comment: Do you have any collections / relations on problematic entity? Could you put entity source code ?

Comment: the entity is pretty large!! but yes there are some relations but all of theme are lazy